# Usage of past tense in present/ regular activities

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, past-tense

I saw this sentence yesterday and it's bugging me: **she still *exercised* every day**.

My question: What is the reason for using past tense in this sentence? Shouldn't it be in the present tense? Can someone explain the grammatical rule behind this?

Comment: It _is_ past tense. The present tense would be 'She still **exercises** every day'.

Answer (score 2):

> She **exercises** every day.

would be a common way to describe her routine.

> Last time I (had) checked (on her), she still **exercised** every day.

would also be a correct sentence describing her routine in the past.